# Find and replace all instances of specific string in multiple files in vim

Tags: vim, vi

I'm still relatively new to Vim and can't figure out how to replace all instances of a specific string in multiple files (from a specific project directory). Ideally I want to do this without any additional plugins; was looking into :vimgrep and :arg options but can't work it out.

Thanks for your time in advance!

Comment: Now that you have some answers to your question, it's [encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to upvote any good answers, and to accept one (if you feel it answered the Q well enough). As usual romainl's answer is better than mine :)

Comment: Just two different but valid approaches.

Answer (score 17):

The general workflow is:

1. Search for your pattern across the project.
2. Operate on each match (safer, slower) or on each file with matches (riskier, faster).
3. Write your changes.

The first step can be done with any command that populates the quickfix list: `:help :vimgrep`, `:help :grep`, something from a third-party plugin, etc.

Taking `:grep` as an example:

```
:grep foo **/*.js
```

will populate the quickfix list with an entry for every `foo` found in `*.js` files in the current directory and subcategories. You can see the list with `:cwindow`.

The second step involves `:help :cdo` or `:help :cfdo`:

```
:cdo s/foo/bar/gc
```

which will substitute every `foo` with `bar` on each line in the quickfix list and ask for confirmation. With `:cfdo` it would look like that:

```
:cfdo %s/foo/bar/gc
```

If you are super confident, you can drop the `c` at the end. See `:help :s_flags`.

The third step involves `:help :update`:

```
:cfdo update
```

which will write every file in the quickfix list to disk if they have been changed.

In short:

```
:gr foo **/*.js
:cdo s/foo/bar/gc
:cfdo up
```

Comment: This worked too. Thank you very much for your help; I like the fact this allows you to operate on each match.

Comment: I feel like doing `:cfdo %s/foo/bar/gc` can have unexpected effects as opposed to `:cdo s/foo/bar/gc` because the former does the change file-wide and the later does it only on the entries visible in the quickfix list. But this can be rare as an instance in the file is most likely in the quickfix list.

Comment: @RaZ0rr I also prefer `:cdo` over `:cfdo`.

Answer (score 3):

You can run a standard substitute command on all lines of all files of the arg
list like so:

`:argdo %s/pattern/replacement/ge`

And if you want to add all files from a particular directory to the arg list,
you can use:

```
argadd `path/to/dir/*.py`
```

Notice the backticks in the above example.

See a good series of screen casts about how to do more
[here](http://vimcasts.org/categories/vimgrep/) and see [this
episode](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/project-wide-find-and-replace/) in
particular.

Comment: Worked a treat, thank you very much for this! Looks like a brilliant screen cast series as well, can't believe I haven't bumped into this yet.

Comment: @John_L_Smith Glad it helped - The guy behind the screen cast series also has a book 'Practical Vim by Drew Neil' which is well worth a read (there is also a second one, 'Modern Vim', but I think it's less useful).